# How to append and pass a Node* parameter at the end of the linked list with C++?

Tags: c++

- I'm trying to create the `append()` member function which takes a pointer to a `PatientList` object as parameter and returns nothing.
- The node passed as a parameter is appended to the end of the linked list.
- For this problem  a node of a list is a `List*` object.

I come here to try to get some help.

[EDITED]

If there is something that is not understandable tell me and I will try to update my post as soon as possible.

First I have 2 classes with member functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Patient {
   public:
    Patient();
    Patient(std::string name);
    ~Patient();
    std::string get_name(void);

   private:
    std::string _name;

   protected:
};

Patient::Patient() : _name("Patient") {}

Patient::Patient(std::string name) : _name(name) {}

Patient::~Patient() {}

std::string Patient::get_name(void) { return _name; }

class PatientList {
private:
    Patient *_content;
    PatientList *_next;
    PatientList *_prev;

public:
    PatientList() = default;
    PatientList(Patient *patient);
    ~PatientList();
    bool isEnd(void);
    void append(PatientList *node);
    Patient *getContent();
    PatientList *getNext();
    void setNext(PatientList *next);
    void setContent(Patient *content);
    void PrintList();
};

PatientList::PatientList(Patient *content)
    : _content(content), _next(nullptr) {}
PatientList::~PatientList() {}
bool PatientList::isEnd() {
    if (_next == nullptr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
Patient *PatientList::getContent() { return _content; }
PatientList *PatientList::getNext() { return _next; }
void PatientList::setNext(PatientList *next) { this->_next = next; }
void PatientList::setContent(Patient *content) { this->_content = content; }

// Function for display list
void PatientList::PrintList() {
    PatientList *temp = this;
    std::cout << "Patients : ";
    while (temp) {
        // For verify if between 2 nodes there are something nullptr.
        if (temp->_next == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "NULLPTR ";
        }
        std::cout << temp->_content->get_name() << " ";
        temp = temp->_next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void PatientList::append(PatientList *node) {
      // or PatientList* newNode = new PatientList(node->_content); I hesitate...
    PatientList *newNode = new PatientList;
    newNode->_content = node->_content;
    PatientList *temp = this;
    while (temp->_next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->_next;
    }
    temp->_next = node;
    newNode->_prev = temp;  // maybe i dont need it ?
}

int main() {
    Patient k1("name1");
    Patient k2("name2");
    Patient k3("name3");
    Patient k4("name4");
    Patient k5("name5");

    PatientList P1(&k1);
    PatientList P2(&k2);
    PatientList P3(&k3);
    PatientList P4(&k4);
    PatientList P5(&k5);

    P1.append(&P2);
    P1.append(&P3);
    P1.append(&P4);
    P1.append(&P5);

    P1.PrintList();
}
```

Output:

```
Patients : name1 name2 name3 name4 NULLPTR name5
```

Output request:

```
Patients : name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
```

So, I have a new problems:

- There is something null before the last node. I dont understand why.
- Where does the problem come from? `append`, `PrintList`, or somewhere else?

[EDITED]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's much more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: I recommend you separate the list from the nodes. So you have a `struct PatientNode { PatientNode* _next; Patient _patient; };` inside your list, and keep a list of those nodes. I also recommend you keep a pointer to the tail node of the list, which makes it *much* easier to append to the end of the list.

Comment: `void PatientList::append(PatientList *node)` doesn't look right. You surely meant `void PatientList::append(Patient* node)`. When implementing a (non-static) class method in object oriented programming you have to consider you are an instance (object) of that class, with all the member variables at your avail (e.g. `content`, `next`...). That is, **you don't need to pass the instance (object) as a parameter**.

Comment: Side note: It's usually better to append (and just about everything else for that matter) the data rather than a node. Let the linked list manage the little implementation details like nodes. The user shouldn't care what's actually in the container or how the container works, so long as it does work. All they should need to know is "I put data in and I get data out." As soon as they know more, there's more room for things to go wrong and more work when you have to change how the container stores data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok i will try with a structure, but i dont understand why i need it.

Comment: @rturrado I understand what you are telling me and i'm agree with you but When i read the instructions :
"append() member function which takes a pointer to a PatientList as parameter and returns nothing.
The node passed as a parameter is appended to the end of the linked list."
i understand `void PatientList::append(PatientList *node)` and not `void PatientList::append(Patient* node)`. Maybe I misunderstood the instructions ? Maybe there is something wrong with the instructions ?

Comment: @Just_a_Beginner Sorry about that! My fault. I thought it was your class design, but I see it is actually the exercise wording. You can indeed implement a `PatientList` class containing some `Patient` info and a `PatientList` pointer to the next node. But I find that confusing. For example, if I read a method signature such as `void PatientList::append(PatientList*)` I would interpret that you are trying to append a list, and not a single node. As Some programmer dude pointed out, I would keep lists and nodes apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible implementation for a `PatientList` class (basically a wrap-up of the comments above):

- It uses smart pointers.
- It only has two public methods (at the moment), `empty()`, and `void append(Patient patient)`.
- It adds a convenience `tail_` pointer, useful for appending nodes.
- Users append patients as `patient_list.append(Patient{ "name" });`.
  They don't know anything about the list implementation.
- `Patient`, `PatientNode`, and `PatientList` are different entities.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/v14YMEhhn)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <memory>  // make_unique, unique_ptr
#include <string>

struct Patient {
    std::string name_;
    Patient() : name_{ "Patient" } {}
    explicit Patient(std::string name) : name_{ std::move(name) } {}
};

class PatientList {
private:
    struct PatientNode {
        Patient patient_;
        std::unique_ptr<PatientNode> next_;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<PatientNode> head_;
    PatientNode* tail_;
public:
    bool empty() {
        return not head_;
    }
    void append(Patient patient) {
        if (empty()) {
            head_ = std::make_unique<PatientNode>(std::move(patient));
            tail_ = head_.get();
        } else {
            tail_->next_ = std::make_unique<PatientNode>(std::move(patient));
            tail_ = tail_->next_.get();
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PatientList& l) {
        os << "[";
        for (auto node_ptr{ l.head_.get() }; node_ptr; node_ptr = node_ptr->next_.get()) {
            os << (node_ptr == l.head_.get() ? "" : ", ") << node_ptr->patient_.name_;
        }
        return os << "]";
    }
};

int main() {
    PatientList pl{};
    pl.append(Patient{ "p3" });
    pl.append(Patient{ "p2" });
    pl.append(Patient{ "p1" });
    std::cout << pl << "\n";
}

// Outputs: [p3, p2, p1]
```

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delay but I was busy.  
First of all thank you for your implementation and your help!  
At the moment your implementation is difficult for me to understand.  
But I made a new implementation, it is not totally correct but I think I am getting closer to the goal.  
If you have a time, can you check a new code pls ?  
Thank you.

Comment: You don't have any problem with the new code. Within `PrintList`, before printing the name of a node, you check if the node is the last in the list (`temp->_next == nullptr`), and, in that case, you print `NULLPTR`. That's probably a debug print you used, but needs to be removed. So, with the debug print, the output is `name1 name2...` and right when you are at the `k5` node, you print `NULLPTR name5`. Remove that debug print, and you will have the expected output: `name1 name2 name3 name4 name5`.

Comment: Sincerely Thank you for your help !

Comment: My pleasure, keep it up!